# Is it a typo in this JSP where it says "</a>>"?

Tags: google-app-engine, jsp, anchor

I found this example in the [App Engine documentation](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/users/package-summary.html).

```
   1 <%
   2  UserService userService = UserServiceFactory.getUserService();
   3  if (!userService.isUserLoggedIn()) {
   4 %>
   5  Please <a href="<%=userService.createLoginURL("/newlogin.jsp")>">log in</a>>
   6 <% } else { %>
   7  Welcome, <%= userService.getCurrentUser().getNickname(); %>!
   8    (<a href="<%=userService.createLogoutURL("/")>">log out</a>>)
   9  <%
   10 }
   11 %>
```

Regarding the `</a>>` at the end of line 5 and line 8: Is that a typo?

If not, why is it supposed to be `</a>>` instead of `</a>` - which is what I expect.

Comment: complete guess. > is a end tag. and to use an actually > u need to escape it > with >.

Comment: Why not try it and find out if it works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's indeed syntactically invalid. I don't think that it's a typo, it's likely just incorrect use of javadoc. HTML entities in javadocs needs to be manually escaped/encoded and this is often overlooked. I also see that *scriptlets* aren't properly closed. Here is the fixed version:

```
<%
   UserService userService = UserServiceFactory.getUserService();
   if (!userService.isUserLoggedIn()) {
%>
      Please <a href="<%= userService.createLoginURL("/newlogin.jsp") %>">log in</a>
<% } else { %>
      Welcome, <%= userService.getCurrentUser().getNickname(); %>!
         (<a href="<%= userService.createLogoutURL("/") %>">log out</a>)
<%
   }
%>
```

*Ugly code by the way. I would just have used a `Filter` and/or a shot of JSTL/EL for this. But that's maybe beyond the capabilities of Google App Engine. Never used it.*